# Attempts of writing/reading firebase realtime database with no results - java server desktop

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, desktop-application

I've been trying the whole day to understand what is happening with my code that is supposed to write and read from Firebase Realtime Database, but no success on it and there's no issue, error, exception or any kind of tip that can help me to figure it out. I'm coding in **java for desktop**, not for Android as all occurrences in my searches return a lot, despite I also coded for Android the same operation using the same database and it worked just fine. I'm consuming too much time and energy on it and I have a too short deadline to hand in it as a project for a discipline that I'm doing, so if someone could help, I'd appreciate a lot!!

As in Android it's perfectly possible to read and write data, I discarded the possibility of the problem to be in DB. I'm following the instructions available in the [Firebase Admin page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). As I said, there's no error, but no result either. With the same configuration and json key file gotten from Firebase console is working properly with Firebase Cloud Messaging, so I considered that the key is ok too.

The code I'm trying is this below, almost the same of the Firebase web page:

```java
package pt.ipp.estg.housecontrol;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class StarterFRD {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("/Users/wdcunha/Development/Java/frdproj/src/main/resources/housecontrolmobile-firebase-adminsdk-qv0hl-f41a07409d.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://housecontrolmobile.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

     // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("users");

        System.out.println("ref: "+ref);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println("document: "+document);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println("canceled: "+error.toException());
            }
        });

        Utilizador utilz = new Utilizador("Euquipe", "eu@quipe.com");

        System.out.println("utilz nome: "+utilz.getNome());
        System.out.println("utilz email: "+utilz.getEmail());

        ref.child("2").push().setValueAsync(utilz);

        ref.child("3").setValue("I'm writing data", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Data saved successfully."+databaseReference);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The database is that one:

[Link to print of the firebase database I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKcFB.png)

When I run the code, I just can take data from the line below with a println (that is just the url from the DB):

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
```

It is set as maven project, so the pom.xml writen is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pt.ipp.estg.housecontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>housecontrolserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>6</source>
                    <target>6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The whole code is in [Github here](https://github.com/wdcunha/FRDServer).

So, that's it guys. I have no clue even after searching and trying many options all day long, I really need help about it. I hope someone can give me a big help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of someone pass through the same difficult, the problem was that I wasn't using  a server to keep it working, so when I run it, there wasn't time enough to receive the feedback. Once I kept it running, it was able to show all communication results from firebase.